# Can't install ubuntu on VMware

Tags: windows, vmware

for some reasons I have to use Windows as my OS. but I need using Linux for other things. so I decided to use ubuntu on VMware.
but every time I want to install it with easy install , it stucks in the middle of it ( in retrieving files step ).
what can I do about it ?

P.S : I mount the ISO setup file of ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot up the Ubuntu disc, you will see in the top right corner that it lists you as connected to the internet, disconnect then begin the installation, you can install any updates you want after the installation is complete.